# automatic presence validation where sql constraint doesn't allow nulls

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

**I dislike nulls in the db**

I have seen too many bugs arises over the years from the sometimes surprising nature of nulls. Especially for columns we don't expect to contain nulls we can easily fail to think through their implications and get bad results. I am strong believer that emptiness for string fields (if allowed) should typically be represented in the db as an empty strings vs a null. (The worst though is allowing a mix of both where they both mean the same thing.)

So because of my experience with past problems, I've methodically considered each field and added the constraint :null => false to any field in the db that I didn't have a good reason to allow nulls. For cases where I want to allow empty strings, I set that as the default.

So far so good.

**I like how ruby treats default values**

As I've done this I've noticed that ActiveRecord takes my default defined in the DB and initializes the properties on the object with that value. I love that!

But this has left me wanting more. Because now I find that I am adding code like

```
validates :name, :presence => true
```

every case where I've defined a not-null constraint in the db except those cases where I've chosen to provide a default empty string. But why am I repeating myself? So I'm thinking--wouldn't it be nice if ActiveRecord did this for me?

**How can I add validating presence from db properties**

Is there a way I can automatically create these validations for every case where there is a not null constraint in the db--except in the special case where I allow empty strings and signal that by setting that as the default?

Bonus: If there is a way to get rails to add a check for different than empty string into the db column and then only automatically add the validation of presence for string fields if they have both the not null constraint and then not empty string check, that would be truly great. Just don't know if that is possible.

Comment: Once you understand NULL-handling its nature will become surprisingly less surprising.

Comment: True, but prevention is also great. Especially when you are talking about managing a team with turnover.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can achieve something like that by adding an [observer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#observers) that will do the validation by default. However, I'm not sure if there's a way to cancel the action from the observer method like you could do with callbacks.